# Backward elimination in a multinomial logistic regression model?

Tags: r, stepwise-regression, multinomial-logit

Following [this UCLA article](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/), I have fit a multinomial logistic regression model in R (say that `Group` is a factor with levels `Control`, `MildDisease`, `SevereDisease`):

```
require(nnet)
data <- read.csv('./data.csv')
data$Group <- relevel(data$Group, ref = "Control")
model <- multinom(Group ~ A + B + C + D, data = data)
```

I'd now like to prune the model to only the relevant predictors.  If this were a binomial logistic regression, I would successively [remove the predictor with the largest p-value until all p-values](http://www.stephacking.com/multivariate-linear-regression-python-step-6-backward-elimination/) until all predictors satisfied `p < 0.05`.  In this case, there are *two* p-values for each predictor (one for `MildDisease` and one for `SevereDisease`).

**How can backward elimination be applied to multinomial logistic regression?**

Answer (score 1):

Backward elimination (and forward, and stepwise) are bad methods for creating a model. You shouldn't use it for binomial logistic or anything else.

By choice, I would not use *any* automated method of variable selection. Use substantive knowledge.

Comment: I've noticed you stating this a couple of times and I would be curious to know the logic behind it. I understand why stepwise regression can be inefficient when too many predictors are involved but I believe it can work out well in scenarios with fewer variables. Also when you have too many variables to select from and substantive knowledge is unavailable or unwanted, shouldn't some sort of model selection mechanism exist (such as AIC minimisation, p-value selection, or regularisation)?

Comment: @Digio For a full explanation see Regression Modeling Strategies by Frank Harrell.  You could also search this site, as it has been discussed many times.  Briefly, when you use forward, backward or stepwise, all the output is demonstrably wrong.  Standard errors are too small, p values are too small, models are too complex, parameter estimates are biased away from 0.

Comment: It is still unclear to me whether the problem lies in using p-values as an optimisation criterion or in the fact that stepwise/backwards/forward methods perform local search instead of global (because both of these aspects are tweakable). I'll also check out your source.

Comment: It's because all the statistics are based on considering a single model that is specified a priori.